# Not able to get geolocation when app is minimized or closed

Tags: react-native, geolocation, background-service

I am working on a project in which i have to use geolocation of the staff. i am able to get the notification with "[@react-native-community/geolocation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/geolocation)" as soon as i minimize the app or close the app it stop working.I also use "[react-native-background-actions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-actions)" to start the background task, same issue with this.Task start successfully but stop working when i close the app or minimize.

Answer (score 1):

to get user location in background you have to user in iOS you have to use `Background Modes -> Location Updates and Background Processing` , while in android you have to create **headless service** (headless service does not work in iOS)

Follow [this](https://medium.com/reactbrasil/how-to-create-an-unstoppable-service-in-react-native-using-headless-js-93656b6fd5d1) tutorial to create a headless service

[image: Please see this image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i already do this (headless service), but service stoped when i close the app or minimized. do you have any git repo or snippet for the same so i can compare the code.?

Comment: you have also to add battery optimisation permission . use this package https://github.com/losthakkun/react-native-battery-optimization-check

Comment: okky, but are you sure this package will start background location tracking ?

Comment: this package will make sure that the headless service is not killed .

Comment: additionally use can use other service for android like boardcast receiver and  clipboard manager, alram manager like strive to make sure app is running when killed.

Comment: sounds good, will check. Thanks a lot